# WPF MetroDialog thread can't access object because a different thread owns it

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to implement a input dialog but I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a threading issue when I click ok or cancel.

Below is my code segment where I'm creating the dialog and showing it, I looked at some examples and answer but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

```
var metroDialogSettings = new MetroDialogSettings()
{
    AffirmativeButtonText = "OK",
    NegativeButtonText = "CANCEL",
    AnimateHide = true,
    AnimateShow = true,
    ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented,
};

var dialog = new AddStorageAccountDialog(MainWindowHelper.mainWindow, metroDialogSettings);


await Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(async () =>
{
    await MainWindowHelper.mainWindow.ShowMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
    await dialog.WaitForButtonPressAsync().ContinueWith((m) =>
    {
        MainWindowHelper.mainWindow.HideMetroDialogAsync(dialog);
    });

    var displayname = dialog.DisplayName;
    var accountname = dialog.AccountName;
    var accountkey = dialog.AccountKey;
});
```

Comment: Isn't the Hide Dialog method of MahApps.Metro a Task? Perhaps you should take it out of continueWith and await it on the line after `WaitForButtonPressAsync`.

Comment: I tried moving the hide out but that didn't help.

Comment: Hm, did you also `await` it?

Comment: Yes I  put await on all the async task. I'm basing my input dialog off https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/Dialogs/InputDialog.cs